# Drop down not working for magento configurable products in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, magento

In my magento website, for configurable products, there is a dropdown-select box to select product options. It works fine in all browsers such as chrome, mozilla firefox. But in IE(all versions), I can select an option for the first time, after that I can't change my option by clicking the drop down.

To change my option, I have to click the mouse outside of dropdown select box and can change the option.

Again to change the option, I have to click the mouse outside of dropdown select box again.

I checked 3 more magento websites in IE. They too had the same issue. When I searched on it, I came  to know onclick function does not work in IE. Then I searched onclick function in config.js file, but I could not get such onclick event function in that file.

Am I doing right? Can anyone give me suggestion to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of issues with Magento dropdowns in IE.

Two things to try:

**1)** Make sure you have the latest 1.x jQuery.

**2)** Add this to `head.phtml` file for your theme:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Comment: I tried this. It didn't work. An Important thing I forgot to mention is that this issue occurs only for windows7 and windows8.

Comment: Looks like Windows Web Server 2012 IE also having this issue.

Comment: I used like this    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />     because my site works fine in the document mode of IE7 for all OS.